# Asking an unanswered question again

Tags: support, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

If I have a question which was unanswered, or if I didn't receive satisfactory answers for it, do I ask the question again (by typing the whole thing again), or there is a way of bringing back this question so that it may be answered?

Comment: Which question? It looks like you have asked several questions that have answers where you haven’t accepted any of the answers. Linking the question here is another way for it to get attention.

Comment: I am talking about questions in general, not about a specific one. You might find answers, but they may not always answer your question *completely.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you ask it again, it will be closed as a duplicate. Please do not do that.

A much better option, and one designed for this exact purpose, is to add a bounty to the question. That will bump the post to the front page and include it in the featured questions list.

Comment: Ok, this made it clear.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider is that in most cases (with the possible exception of some software questions that just seem to not attract attention), there's some reason why there are no satisfactory answers. Things to look into include whether it's on-topic or not, whether the question can be answered subjectively, is the question easy to read/understand, is the question just hard to answer for some other reason, etc. I've had a question ('kay, maybe two or three) like that, and I edited to try to get people to answer it, checking for those things and improving it. When that failed, I posted a bounty (with limited success, but it was something, at least). The bounty got me some answers, but I came to the conclusion that my question probably wasn't going to get me any satisfactory answers, and I think it was because it was just something that not a lot of people would be able to answer (it was pretty specific).

Bit of a rant, but my point is that **I recommend all users check their questions first to see if there's anything that can be fixed. After that, I'll defer to the Doc's answer above.**

And also try other SE sites. Some of them may have the answers [Physics has been helpful to me, but maybe not to everyone :)]!